# Error E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Muy buenas a todos y antes que nada gracias por leer esto

Llevo un par de días tirandome de los pelos porque intento crear en android studio una aplicación, pero no logro pasar de el intento de crear la cuenta del usuario, uso PHP, wamp y android studio pero no hay manera, este es el error que me sale:

```
E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
V/params: [nombre=afafa, clave=afafa, correo=afa, pregunta=1 ¿En que ciudad nació?, respuesta=1313, informacion=1]
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
              Process: com.example.bruno.thulin, PID: 27878
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.bruno.thulin.inicio.CrearCuenta$CrearNuevoUsuario.doInBackground(CrearCuenta.java:215)
                  at com.example.bruno.thulin.inicio.CrearCuenta$CrearNuevoUsuario.doInBackground(CrearCuenta.java:164)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Lo he intentado de mil maneras pero no encuentro la solución, este es mi código:

el php para crear usuario:

crear_usuario.php

```
<?php

/*
 *Este código creará los usuarios nuevos
 */ 

// Array para la respuesta del JSON

 $response = array();

// comprobación de los campos requeridos

 if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['clave']) && isset($_POST['correo']) && isset($_POST['pregunta']) && isset($_POST['respuesta'])) {

 $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
 $clave = $_POST['clave'];
 $correo = $_POST['correo'];
 $pregunta = $_POST['pregunta'];
 $respuesta = $_POST['respuesta'];
 $informacion = $_POST['informacion'];

 // se incluye la clase de db connect

 include('db_connect.php');

 // Conectando con la bd

 $db = new DB_CONNECT();

 // mysql insertando nueva fila

 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","thulin","","thulin");

 $result = mysqli_query($link,'INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, clave, correo, pregunta, respuesta, informacion) VALUES ($nombre, $clave, $correo, $pregunta, $respuesta, $informacion)');

 // Comprobación de si la fila se ha insertado o no

 if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Cuenta creada con exito.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Ha ocurrido un error.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Falta algún campo";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Y esta es la clase en Android Studio que llama al php y debería de crear la cuenta:

CrearCuenta.java

```
package com.example.bruno.thulin.inicio;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.bruno.thulin.R;
import com.example.bruno.thulin.json.JSONparser;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CrearCuenta extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etNombre, etPassword, etCorreo, etRespuesta;
private Button btnCrearCuenta;
private CheckBox informacion;
private boolean pregunta;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private JSONparser jsonParser = new JSONparser();
private static String url_crear_usuario;
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private String nombre;
private String password;
private String correo;
private String eleccion;
private String respuesta;
private String infostring;
private int info;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crear_cuenta);


    final Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinnercreacioncuenta);
    etNombre = findViewById(R.id.etnombrecreacioncuenta);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etpasswordcreacioncuenta);
    etCorreo = findViewById(R.id.etcorreocreacioncuenta);
    etRespuesta = findViewById(R.id.etrespuestacreacioncuenta);
    btnCrearCuenta = findViewById(R.id.btncrearcuenta);
    informacion = findViewById(R.id.checkinfocreacioncuenta);
    url_crear_usuario = "http://192.168.8.100/thulin/crear_usuario.php";

    final Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/doriel.otf");

    final String[] items = new String[]{"1.- ¿En que ciudad nació?", "2.- ¿Cual es el nombre de su primer amor?", "3.- ¿Como se llama su pareja actual?", "4.- ¿De que raza es su perro?", "5.- ¿Como se llama su perro?", "6.- ¿Como se llamaba su primer instituto?", "7.- ¿Como se llama su madre?", "8.- ¿Como se llama su padre?"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner_style, items) {

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(16);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(type);

            Log.v("estoy aqui", items.toString());

            return v;

        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,parent);

            ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(type);

            return v;

        }

    };

    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);


    etNombre.setTypeface(type);
    etPassword.setTypeface(type);
    etCorreo.setTypeface(type);
    etRespuesta.setTypeface(type);
    btnCrearCuenta.setTypeface(type);
    informacion.setTypeface(type);

    btnCrearCuenta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ( etNombre.getText().toString().equals("") || etPassword.getText().toString().equals("") || etCorreo.getText().toString().equals("") || etRespuesta.toString().equals("")) {
                if (etNombre.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast ToastVacio = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No has puesto el nombre", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    ToastVacio.show();
                }

                else if (etPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast ToastVacio = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No has puesto la contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    ToastVacio.show();
                }

                else if (etCorreo.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast ToastVacio = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No has puesto el correo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    ToastVacio.show();
                }

                else if (etRespuesta.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast ToastVacio = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No has puesto una respuesta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    ToastVacio.show();
                }
            }

            else {
                nombre = etNombre.getText().toString();
                password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                correo = etCorreo.getText().toString();
                eleccion = dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                respuesta = etRespuesta.getText().toString();

                if (informacion.isChecked()) {
                    info = 1;
                }

                else {
                    info = 0;
                }

                new CrearNuevoUsuario().execute();


            }

        }
    });

}


@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class CrearNuevoUsuario extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CrearCuenta.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creando Usuario");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters


        infostring = Integer.toString(info);


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair ("nombre", nombre));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clave", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("correo", correo));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pregunta", eleccion));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("respuesta", respuesta));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("informacion", infostring));

        Log.v("nombre", nombre);
        Log.v("clave", password);
        Log.v("correo", correo);
        Log.v("eleccion", eleccion);
        Log.v("respuesta", respuesta);
        Log.v("informacion", infostring);

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_crear_usuario,
                "POST", params);

        Log.v("params", params.toString());


        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InicioPersonaje.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

Un saludo a todos, y espero que me puedan ayudar, se me da muy bien android studio y soy programador, pero no tengo mucha idea de servidores y php y estoy empezando en ese campo.

Gracias de antemano.

Clase JSONparser.java:

```
package com.example.bruno.thulin.json;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONparser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONparser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Comment: Parece que intentas parsear algo a JSON y no es del tipo json. Por favor, sube el json que te devuelve la consulta porque parece que falla al ibntentar hacer la conversión

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano añadido JSONparser.java.

Comment: No la clase parser, sino el JSon que recibes porque parece que es eso lo qfalla, al intentar parsear el JSon, por eso te digo, pega el JSon que recibes para ver si lo que intentas parsear tiene el formato correcto

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Disculpa la pregunta compañero pero como hago eso o donde se ve? perdona mi ignorancia pero soy bastante nuevo en php y json xD

Comment: A tienes cuando haces $response = array(); en $response tienes el json.

Comment: si pero cuando estoy en android studio es justo ahi donde da el error, cuando va a obtener la respuesta con Log.d("Create Response", json.toString()); es cuando salta el error.

Comment: Haz un log de esto jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_crear_usuario,
                "POST", params); antes de crear el JSONObject para ver lo que te devuelve la llamada http

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano

He intentado hacer el log de esto: Log.v("params", jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_crear_usuario, "POST", params).toString());


y me sale el mismo error, principalmente las dos lineas importantes del error son:

E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
y

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Si pongo el url en mi navegador va bien (salta que falta algun campo obviamente pero lo que es conectar lo hace)

Comment: Parece que el objeto JSONObject es nulo, puedes comprobar que la llamada no te devuelve un null?

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano

he hecho esto: if (json!= null ){
                Log.v("nulo", "no es nulo");
            }
            else{
                Log.v("nulo", "es nulo");
            }

Y me sale efectivamente que es nulo, donde esta el problema a la hora de hacer el json? me falta algo?

Comment: Hay que ver lo que te devuelve la llamada http

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano como miro eso?

Y sobretodo gracias por la ayuda que me estás prestando, de verdad, soy un verdadero noob en temas de json y servidores xD

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano


Hice esto y me salió que el http era nulo:

  if ((jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_crear_usuario, "POST", params) == null)) {
                Log.v("nulo", "el http es nulo");
            }